# TableView sections don't seem to work Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

The problem I am encountering is that I don't know how to code my tableViewController properly, so it displays 2 sections, one with Items (object type) which value is higher than 50, and second section for Items valued less than 50. My code looks like this:

```
@implementation ItemsViewController

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    if(self)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            [[ItemStore sharedStore] createItem];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSArray<NSString *> *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
{
    return @[@">50", @"<=50"];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        return [[[ItemStore sharedStore] itemsValuedOver50] count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [[[ItemStore sharedStore] itemsValuedBelowOrEqual50] count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        NSArray *items = [[ItemStore sharedStore] itemsValuedOver50];

        NSArray *item = items[indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = [item description];

    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *items = [[ItemStore sharedStore] itemsValuedBelowOrEqual50];

        NSArray *item = items[indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = [item description];
    }

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Section names (">50" and <=50) appear in the middle of the right side of the screen(looks like it is out of the table view), and the table view still behaves as it had only one section. These 5 items are not sorted in any way and I have no idea why.

Here is the link to screenshot of the application: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mre0C.jpg

I've been looking for answer for some time, but to be fair i don't know how to describe my problem well enough to find any solution online, thats why I'm creating a new topic.

Thanks for your help in advance.

**EDIT:** I've figured out the problem. It took me few days and it was preety stupid. I used wrong method. Instead of using sectionIndexTitlesForTableView: i should have used titleForHeaderInSection:. Now everything works as i wanted it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the section height via the delegate

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForSection:(NSUInteger)section;
```

Comment: I used this method and made it just return 20, but it changed nothing.